Is there a way to generate requirements.txt for the libraries that are imported in Jupyter notebook in Pycharm
I wanted to generate a requirements.txt for all the libraries that I imported in a project which ad two py files and one ipynb, but in Pycharm I could generate a requirement.txt for just py files and it is not generating the necessary library names for jupyter notebook.
I tried using "Sync Python requirements" tool in pycharm but it generated the requirement.txt for the libraries in python files only and didnt add any library names that were in Jupyter notebookPycharm tool for generating requirements.txt

Can't you just use search to find import ... or from ... import statements and jot down your requirements? You could also pip freeze your current environment into a requirements.txt file.

This should be closed as already covered many places here. Example here.

This question is similar to: Pip freeze for only project requirements. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can try with
pip freeze > requirements.txt

this saves all the packages currently installed to requirements.txt file
